# Is this site still open?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for information for a clients 2 1/2 year old grandson and came across the site.  I was wondering if it was still current?

Comment: Have you taken the [tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and looked at the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help)?  I think you might be confused about the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this site is still “open”.

I would recommend you take the [tour](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/tour) and browse through the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) as suggested in a previous comment.

Everyone is welcome to [ask questions about parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and post answers to existing questions. The existing questions and answers form a knowledge base that can and should help not only one specific asker, but future readers with the same problem as well. That’s why it’s always a good idea to use the search function and the related questions suggested by the system before posting a question.

When you ask about whether the site is open, please note that the whole Stack Exchange model is based on volunteers forming a community and sharing their expertise. Participation can and does fluctuate, that’s fine for us. It’s not a „service“ where you can demand responses e.g. within a certain time frame. Ask clear and interesting questions and the community is likely to upvote your post and answer fast and in a helpful way.